# Setuptools python - import problem inside project

Tags: python, import, python-import, setuptools, setup.py

I'm trying to build simple project and then prepare it to create whl file. But after `pip install <name>.whl` I have strange import problem.
Project structure:

```
foo/
    /foo
        __init__.py
        main.py
        bar.py
    setup.py
```

setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['foo=foo.main:func1']}
)
```

main.py

```
from bar import func2

def func1():
    print('func1')
    func2()
```

bar.py

```
def func2():
    print('func2')
```

I have an empty init file.

I create whl file by command: `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`
and then `cd dist/ && pip install ...`

But when I run script by `foo` I got an error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'

This problem exists only when I have splited project in a few files, when I tried to keep everything in main.py (removed bar.py) without imports then it worked.

Any idea how should I modify setup.py?

Comment: I think the problem is with your _imports_, not your `setup.py`.  I think that it should be be `from foo.bar import func2`?  (Or if you want to use inter-package imports, `from .bar import func2`)

Comment: heh, thank you, I didn't expected that :)

Comment: No problem.  I have a couple minutes now -- I'll expand on that a little and write it up as an answer in the hope that maybe it'll help someone else someday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your *imports* -- not your `setup.py`.  What is happening is that your `setup.py` is installing the package `foo` which has submodules `main` and `bar`.

To import a function from a submodule, you do something like:

```
from foo.bar import func2
```

or, if you are doing a package relative import (e.g. importing `bar` from `main`):

```
from .bar import func2
```

This second version won't work if the module that is doing the importing isn't part of the `foo` package.